# Which way to delete/drop a column from a big table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

My table has 119962649 rows and is over 600 GB in size.

I want to delete/drop one column of type `nvarchar(MAX)`.

Which is the best way to do so?

Help me, thank you.

Comment: What happens when you use `alter table X drop column Y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `alter table tab drop column col;`. But if you have a big table or PK,FK, check constraint, or indexes defined on it, then you need to be careful.
So, here are my thoughts -

1. backup the table.

```
select * into tab_bkp from  old_tab;
```

2. if that column has constraint, you need to drop it first.

```
alter table tab drop constraint cons_1;
```

3. Drop column from table.

```
alter table tab drop column col;
```

4. Check data. Anything wrong, you can retrieve data from tab_bkp.

Comment: Hi bro , I would like to know what are bad importances will be happen?when I do this.For example IO/CPU/Table lock or other.

Comment: the idea is very good but Sqlserver drop does not free space.how can I free space

Comment: It should. Any issues you are facing specifically?

Comment: after execute "alter table tab drop constraint cons_1;" I execute "exec sp_spaceused 'tab '"

Comment: the reserved  doesn't  change

Comment: my statement is pseudo code. you need to check `your` table definition and get constraint name and replace constraint_name in my query.

Answer (score 0):

If that column you want to drop is where the majority of your code is stored, it might also be an idea to actually:

1. Create a new table (without that column you want to drop)
2. Copy over the data from the other columns into that new table
3. Drop your existing table (possibly first dropping FK and other constraints)
4. Rename the newly created table (with the data) to the old table name (and re-establish any constraints you need)

Comment: Hi bro , I would like to know what are bad importances will be happen?when I do this.For example IO/CPU/Table lock or other.